# Django-Filter: multiple select2 choices on a foreign-key field

Tags: django, jquery-select2, django-filter

I'm having a multiple select 2 like this:

[image: 1]

The filter needs to return all the Route Template that matches the mentioned select 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Model:

```
from django.db import models
class Route(models.Model):
    route_template = models.ForeignKey(RouteTemplate, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Filter:

```
import django_filters

class RouteFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    route_template = django_filters.AllValuesMultipleFilter(field_name='route_template__name')
```

I've struggled a lot with MutlipleChoice, overriding method, etc. and the solution is `AllValuesMultipleFilter`